# Boto3: Unable to set Metadata on put/upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

The following code :

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='AKIA...',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
    aws_session_token=True
        )
client.put_object(
    Bucket=input_bucket,
    Key=file_name_final,
    Body=open(tmp_file_name, 'r'),
    Metadata={'a':'b'}
)
```

Crashes with :

`Metadata={'a':'b'} TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

On the other hand, using a Resource :

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='AKIA...',
    aws_secret_access_key='m/twhd6ow8aRuf+gjQcL8gu+bS5Y3tAVjcTe1+ai',
    aws_session_token=True
)
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(input_bucket)
upfile = my_bucket.Object(file_name_final);
meta = {'a':'b'}
upfile.upload_file(
    tmp_file_name,
    ExtraArgs={"Metadata":meta}
)
```

crashes with `ExtraArgs={"Metadata":meta} : AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'split'`

I think I have tried all the variations on str('b','utf-8/ascii'), .encode() and .decode() and some very silly things, but nothing. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Object('input_bucket', 'file_name_final').put(Body='hello world', Metadata={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Ref: [boto3-s3-put-documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put)

Comment: nope, tried that too, same than the second example in my post ('bool' object has no attribute 'split')

Comment: could you run this as a separate script and see if you have errors ? This is a working code from my side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to upload I used:

```
s3=boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file("file","destinationBucket","destinationFile",ExtraArgs={"Metadata":{"meta1:val1","meta2:val2"})
```